# Handling Fabric's stdout under mod_wsgi?

Tags: mod-wsgi, fabric

I'm working on an API that deploys code to different servers using Fabric. It works when I run it using gunicorn, but when I switch to Apache and mod_wsgi, the stdout restrictions kick in.

I tried `sys.stdout = sys.stderr` in my wsgi script, but instead of an IOError I get

```
AttributeError: 'mod_wsgi.Log' object has no attribute 'isatty'
```

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your mod_wsgi version. Looks like you are using very old version.